# Changing HStore Column to Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, hstore

I have a column in my Rails/Postgres app that I want to change from Hstore to an Array. (I was storing phones as a hash, so I could do `{default: 123, mobile: 1234}`, but decided it wasn't necessary/useful)

So I did the following migration:

```
class ChangePhonesToArray < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    new_phones = {}
    Place.find_each do |p|
      new_phones[p.id] = p.phones.values.map{ |v| v.gsub(%r!\D!, '') } # get rid of non-number characters while I'm at it
    end

    remove_column :places, :phones

    add_column :places, :phones, :string, array: true, default: []

    new_phones.each do |k, v|
      p = Place.find(k)
      p.update_attributes!(phones: v)
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

When I do that, however, I get this nasty DB error, suggesting that `phones` is still an Hstore column!

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

can't cast Array to hstore/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:76:in `type_cast'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb:111:in `type_cast'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:828:in `block in exec_cache'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:827:in `map'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:827:in `exec_cache'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `exec_delete'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:101:in `update'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `update'
```

I assumed the column wasn't being removed correctly, so I threw a second `remove_column` in there right after the first, and that threw the below error suggesting that the column had already been removed! (But apparently not completely).

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "phones" of relation "places" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "places" DROP "phones"/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.2/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:160:in `exec'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.2/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:160:in `async_exec'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `block in execute'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/sasha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:127:in `execute'
```

Any idea what's going on here, and how to fix/get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you changed the table schema inside the database doesn't mean that your `Place` class knows about those changes. `ActiveRecord::Base` subclasses only load the column information once to avoid needlessly hitting the database over and over again. As soon as you do this:

```
Place.find_each
```

your `Place` will know what the column types are. Then you change the schema behind `Place`'s back and try to write new values but `Place` doesn't know about the changes. The usual way around this is to call [`reset_column_information`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reset_column_information):

> Resets all the cached information about columns, which will cause them to be reloaded on the next request.
>
> The most common usage pattern for this method is probably in a migration...

so you'd just say:

```
#...
remove_column :places, :phones
add_column :places, :phones, :string, array: true, default: []
Place.reset_column_information
#...
```

BTW, there's no guarantee that `hstore` will maintain any sort of order so you might want to `p.phones.values_at(:default, :mobile)` instead of `p.phones.values` to make sure things are in the right order in your array.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about the class itself needing to have its information reset. Cool to learn. Worked like a charm.